Understanding $L^p$ norm over the boundary of a set
I'm currently studying Evans' PDE book. On section 5.5, theorem 1 states that $\lVert Tu \rVert_{L^p(\partial U)} \leq C \lVert u \rVert_{W^{1, p}(U)}$. However, he never defines what $\lVert Tu \rVert_{L^p(\partial U)}$ means. More specifically, I don't understand how to define the $L^p$ norm over a set with Lebesgue measure zero (in this case, $\partial U$). Could anyone clarify how this norm is defined?

You need to carry out integration over a manifold.

@温泽海 what do you mean?

I guess the integration is according to the Lebesgue measure of $\partial U$. What @温泽海
means, I think, is that, if you take say $U=(0,1)^2$ then $\partial U$ is a square so it is of dimension $1$ and the Lebesgue measure on $\partial U$ is not induced by the Lebesgue measure on $U$, so $\lambda_{\partial U}((0,1))=1$ while $\lambda_U((0,1))=0$ for instance.

I don't have the book in front of me, but iirc he discusses in further detail the meaning behind a lot of the measure theory used in the appendices at the end.

@123 I remember struggling exactly the same thing when I started reading Evans. It turns out that the source of the struggle is that one does not know how to deal with the boundary of a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence implying difficulty of understanding topics like integration by parts over a domain or $L^p$ space over the boundary. The remedy is to study manifolds BEFORE starting reading these topics, to the point where you can do integration on manifolds. A reference would be for instance https://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf

@温泽海 Thank you for the reference. I appreciate it!
